# jQuery - Why does $('input').val(char) not update the input value on mobile?

Tags: jquery

I have been looking through Stack Overflow for hours now and still can't find a solution to this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Basically, I've coded up an app that lets a user try to solve cryptograms. I've dynamically created an input field for each letter of the cryptogram, with the encoded letter beneath the input field.

Here is a simplified version of it:

```
var correctString = "HELLO FROM OUTER SPACE";
var encryptedString = "JFPPK QWKC KHRFW ZXIMF";
var encryptedStringWithoutSpaces = encryptedString.replace(/[^a-zA-Z-]/g, '');

/* CREATE INITIAL INPUTS AND DIVS */
$('#container').append('<div class="word"></div>');
for(var i = 0; i < correctString.length; i++) {
    if(correctString[i] === ' ') {
        $('#container').append('<div class="space"></div>')
        $('#container').append('<div class="word"></div>')
    } else {
        $('.word').last().append('<div class="letter"><input name="letter" type="text" maxLength="1"></input><p>'
            + encryptedString[i] + '</p></div>');
    }
}

/* DISPLAY ALL SIMILAR LETTERS TO MOST RECENTLY INPUT VALUE */
$('#container').on('keypress', 'input', function(e) {
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    var index = $('input').index(this);
    for(var i = 0; i < encryptedStringWithoutSpaces.length; i++) {
        if (encryptedStringWithoutSpaces[i] === encryptedStringWithoutSpaces[index] && i != index) {
            $($('input').get(i)).val(char);
        }
    }
});
```

So the problem comes when I tried to code the program to where if the user inputs an 'o' in the input field above the 'k', all the input fields that are above 'k's will have an 'o' in them. This line:

```
$($('input').get(i)).val(char);
```

This works in the browser and when I'm looking at the mobile version of the app in DevTools, but when I opened the app on my actual phone, it didn't work.

Here's the full code for it:

```js
var correctString = "HELLO FROM OUTER SPACE";
var encryptedString = "JFPPK QWKC KHRFW ZXIMF";
var encryptedStringWithoutSpaces = encryptedString.replace(/[^a-zA-Z-]/g, '');

/* CREATE INITIAL INPUTS AND DIVS */
$('#container').append('<div class="word"></div>');
for (var i = 0; i < correctString.length; i++) {
  if (correctString[i] === ' ') {
    $('#container').append('<div class="space"></div>')
    $('#container').append('<div class="word"></div>')
  } else {
    $('.word').last().append('<div class="letter"><input name="letter" type="text" maxLength="1"></input><p>' +
      encryptedString[i] + '</p></div>');
  }
}

/* DISPLAY ALL SIMILAR LETTERS TO MOST RECENTLY INPUT VALUE */
$('#container').on('keypress', 'input', function(e) {
  var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  var index = $('input').index(this);
  for (var i = 0; i < encryptedStringWithoutSpaces.length; i++) {
    if (encryptedStringWithoutSpaces[i] === encryptedStringWithoutSpaces[index] && i != index) {
      $($('input').get(i)).val(char);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}

.letter,
.space {
  display: inline-block;
}

.space {
  width: 40px;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try the more logical `$('input').eq(i).val(char);`, not that it should matter though ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `keypress` event does not fire on mobile devices. A better approach would be to use the `keyup` event and check the value of the input in the event handler instead of the key pressed (to keep non-character keys like <kbd>Tab</kbd> from corrupting the characters in other inputs):

```
/* DISPLAY ALL SIMILAR LETTERS TO MOST RECENTLY INPUT VALUE */
$('#container').on('keyup', 'input', function(e) {
  var char = $(this).val();
  var index = $('input').index(this);
  for (var i = 0; i < encryptedStringWithoutSpaces.length; i++) {
    if (encryptedStringWithoutSpaces[i] === encryptedStringWithoutSpaces[index] && i != index) {
      $($('input').get(i)).val(char);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `keyCode` property on `e` in `$('#container').on('keypress', 'input', function(e) {})`

Instead use something like:

```
var char = e.originalEvent.key.length === 1 ? e.originalEvent.key : '';
```

I'm checking the length is 1 because if you don't you'll end up with "backspace" and "delete" etc as these are valid keys too.

Comment: This is incorrect. `e` does, in fact, have a `keyCode` property, at least on Chrome. The problem, as described in my answer, is that the `keypress` event does not fire on mobile devices.

Comment: @insert_name_here The `keypress` event not firing on mobile may well be part of the reason it doesn't work on mobile but I `console.log(e)` with the OP's jsFiddle in Firefox and it didn't have the `keyCode` property. Consequently it didn't work until I altered it as per my answer.

Comment: Ah, so not all browsers support `keyCode`. That's another problem. However, it can be easily solved by changing `e.keyCode` to `e.which`, which is jQuery's "normalized" version of `keyCode` and works across all browsers. This still doesn't solve the OP's problem, namely the code not working on mobile devices, though.